# jQuery go back to the same place I came from after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with bootstrap 4 tabs to where one tap closes when I open another tab. Each click opens a table. When I click a table cell a modal opens with additional information. When I click a return button on the modal I would like to go back to the table I came from with the table open. 
Right now when I close the modal I go back to the screen with the table closed.

The solution I thought was to simulate a click to open the table after the modal closes. But only the modal closes and the table stays closed.

Here is my jQuery so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#goback').click(function () {
    history.back();
    document.getElementById('viewCustomers').click()
  });
});
```

Comment: Look for [BootStrap events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events) and forget about [history.back()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history)

Answer (score 0):

there is not enough code to determine what to look for. However I'll suggest changing

```
document.getElementById('viewCustomers').click()
```

to

```
$('#viewCustomers').click();
```

or

```
$('#viewCustomers').trigger('click');
```

Comment: His plain JS to trigger a click is correct... The problem is the history back.

Comment: When I leave the modal window without the jquery I first get an empty screen. I need to click backspace and the tab button to get back to the table I started out. Therefore I am attempting to simulate these steps with jQuery. I only archive partial success: I get to the window with the tab buttons but the click on the tab button never happens in the jQuery. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using hash values? that would be the only way i can see this working. in which case (assuming your address is something like `https://site/document.html#hashbeforemodal`) i'd suggest doing `window.location.hash = 'hashbeforemodal'` instead of `history.back` or `window.location.href='thepreviousurl'

Not sure if that last one will work with hashes or if it will refresh the page, in which case it wont work what does the url look like?